# HttpWebResponse.ReadTimeout - Timeouts not supported?

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

We have an issue where on a single instance of our product we receive an InvalidOperationException exception when we attempt to set the ReadTimeout property of an System.Net.HttpWebResponse object.

This issue is occurring only on a single instance, where we have many multiple live sites without this problem. We've tried to recreate the issue locally, to no avail.

The following code illustrates the issue.

Any ideas are greatly welcome.

Thanks

```
    private static XmlReader GenerateReaderFromResponse(HttpWebResponse response, HttpWebRequest request)
    {
        Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        responseStream.ReadTimeout = request.Timeout; //This is where the exception is generated - System.InvalidOperationException: Timeouts are not supported on this stream.

        using (StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(responseStream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            XmlReaderSettings readerSettings = new XmlReaderSettings();
            readerSettings.ProhibitDtd = false;
            string responseContent = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
            return XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(responseContent), readerSettings);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is the [HttpWebRequest.ReadWriteTimeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.readwritetimeout.aspx) property.

It specifies the number of milliseconds before the reading (or writing) operation on the response `Stream` times out, throwing a `WebException` with `Status` set to [WebExceptionStatus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webexceptionstatus.aspx).`RequestCanceled`.

From the [msdn documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.readwritetimeout.aspx):

> The `ReadWriteTimeout` property is used when writing to the stream
>   returned by the `GetRequestStream` method or reading from the stream
>   returned by the `GetResponseStream` method.
>
> Specifically, the `ReadWriteTimeout` property controls the time-out for
>   the `Read` method, which is used to read the stream returned by the
>   `GetResponseStream` method, and for the `Write` method, which is used to
>   write to the stream returned by the `GetRequestStream` method.
>
> To specify the amount of time to wait for the request to complete, use
>   the [Timeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.timeout.aspx) property.

Comment: ShdNx, thanks, we were looking at changing to this...but it still doesn't really answer why we're getting the strange results!

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that `responseStream` and `request` are not null.

Them, you should make sure that the server did respond to your request after trying to read the response from it.

If you can, please also provide the code that sends the request.

Comment: What do you mean by your second statement?